# PHP XML edit existing xml and add data

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

So i have the following xml structure:

```
<Application>
        <Properties>
            <Property>
                <Name>blabla</Name>
                <Value>123</Value>
            </Property>
        </Properties>
</Application>
```

and i want to add another "Property" child with PHP.
an example could be:

```
<Application>
        <Properties>
            <Property>
                <Name>blabla</Name>
                <Value>123</Value>
                                <Name>example test</Name>
                <Value>another value</Value>
            </Property>
        </Properties>
</Application>
```

Here is my current php code:

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("Application.xml"); 

    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML()); 

    $properties = $sxe->addChild("Property");
    $properties->addChild("Name", "namehere"); 
    $properties->addChild("Value", "random value here"); 

    $sxe->asXML("Application.xml");
?>
```

but it just adds it to the end of the xml. After `</Application>` and that is not what we want.

I want it to add it in the `<Property>` child.

Can someone help me?

Comment: `$sxe->Properties->addchild("Property")` is what you want to write.

Comment: in your sample result, there's only one `Property` element with twice the same attribute set, is it what you really want?

Comment: that's what I thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to traverse inside the `<Application>` tag to the `<Properties>` tag.

Use `xpath()`.

```
$propNode = $sxe->xpath('/Application/Properties');
$property = $propNode[0]->addChild('Property');
```

Here's the [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/grj-t83)

Comment: Updated my answer with a working example. There was also an extra `/` in my xpath.

Comment: gives me this error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\account\register\signup.php on line 287

Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\account\register\signup.php on line 287

EDIT: nvm fixed it and it works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your children to a specific element, you have to say so:

```
$properties = $sxe->Properties->addChild("Property");
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Online Demo](http://eval.in/9451)

If there are more than one `Properties` element and you want to specify not the first one, you can use the zero-based array index for that, e.g. `0` for the first one (default), `1` for the second one:

```
$properties = $sxe->Properties[1]->addChild("Property");
```

[Online Demo](http://eval.in/9450)